# Failed to start network time synchronisation error while booting

Tags: boot, 18.04

While I was starting Ubuntu, I suddenly got an error saying:

```
Failed to start network time synchronization
```

I wasn't restarting Ubuntu, I just started my laptop after some hours and I got this error.

Comment: Check System Settings -> Details -> Date & Time.  The "Automatie Date & Time" switch should be ON. If off, turn it on.